# Embedding a video with Gatsby <iframe>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, embedded-video

I've read the docs about this but my attempt has proven incorrect. I am trying to display a embedded video based on the artist page being viewed. In my Json file I have a featuredVideo key which contains the embedded video url. But when I use featuredVideo in my artist component, nothing displays on the screen. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Here is my video component:

```
import React from 'react'
const Video = ({ featuredVideo, videoTitle, ...props }) => (
  <div className='video'>
    <iframe
      src={featuredVideo}
      title={videoTitle}
      allow='accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture'
      frameBorder='0'
      webkitallowfullscreen='true'
      mozallowfullscreen='true'
      allowFullScreen
    />
  </div>
)
export default Video
```

Here is my artist component:

```
import Video from './components/video'
const ArtistContainer = ({ data }) => {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const {
    firstName,
    lastName,
    city,
    currentTeam,
    bio,
    twitter,
    instagram,
    email,
    whatWeLove,
    featuredVideo,
    recentPerformance,
  } = data.artistsJson

  return (
...
 <Video src={`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${featuredVideo}`} />
```

Here is some of the Json file:

```
    "artistId": 59,
    "firstName": ["FirstName"],
    "lastName": ["LastName"],
    "bio": "This is a tester statement for dev purposes. -- blah blah blah blah blah blah blah -- blah blah blah blah blah blah blah",
    "highlight": "",
    "events": ["Winter 2020"],
    "featuredVideo": "C0eBTtXYTp0",
    "currentTeam": "CurrentTeam",
    "instagram": "https://www.instagram.com/wolfofvillage/",
    "city": "City",
    "tiktok": "",
    "twitter": "https://www.twitter.com/test",
    "youtube": "",
    "email": "test@email.com",
    "address": "",
    "phoneNumber": "",
    "whatWeLove": "This is a tester statement for dev purposes -- blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.",
    "recentPerformance": "06/08/2020"
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a `src` prop with the dynamic URL in:

```
 <Video src={`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${featuredVideo}`} />
```

But you are getting `featuredVideo`, `videoTitle` and `...props` (the rest) in:

```
import React from 'react'
const Video = ({ featuredVideo, videoTitle, ...props }) => (
  <div className='video'>
    <iframe
      src={featuredVideo}
      title={videoTitle}
      allow='accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture'
      frameBorder='0'
      webkitallowfullscreen='true'
      mozallowfullscreen='true'
      allowFullScreen
    />
  </div>
)
export default Video
```

I think you are looking for:

```
import React from 'react'
const Video = ({ src , ...props }) => (
  <div className='video'>
    <iframe
      src={src}
      title={`Some title`}
      allow='accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture'
      frameBorder='0'
      webkitallowfullscreen='true'
      mozallowfullscreen='true'
      allowFullScreen
    />
  </div>
)
export default Video
```

Keep in mind that you are not drilling down any further `props` to the `Video` component in `...props` so you will need to refactor the `ArtistContainer` with something like:

```
import Video from './components/video'
const ArtistContainer = ({ data }) => {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const {
    firstName,
    lastName,
    city,
    currentTeam,
    bio,
    twitter,
    instagram,
    email,
    whatWeLove,
    featuredVideo,
    recentPerformance,
  } = data.artistsJson

  return (
...
 <Video src={`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${featuredVideo}`} videoTitle= {videoTitle} />
```

In order to get the `videoTitle` in the children component.